# How to keep the circle, stroke and font size when zooming in d3.js V4 layout?

Tags: d3.js

I'm using d3.v4.js to draw my layout. And I need to limit the circle, stroke and font size to a maximized value when zooming in.

Here's an example that implements what I want, but it's in d3.v3.js.

http://bl.ocks.org/eyaler/10586116

I don't know how to implement this in d3.v4.js. Can anybody help me? Thanks.

Comment: with `zoom.scaleExtent([extent])` you can limit the maximum zoom scale, if you want to draw all at a constant size while zoom you must modify the attributes based on the current scale

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way I can think of is applying a "counter-scale" on the nodes when zooming.

When you zoom, a `scale` transformation is applied to the `<g>` wrapper node that is direct child of the `svg` node.

Let `MAX_SCALE` be the max scale you want to be applied on the nodes.
Let `currentScale` the scale that's applied with the current zoom.

if (`currentScale` > `MAX_SCALE`), apply the "counter-scale" on the nodes (let's admit they are tagged with a "limit-scale" class):

```
d3.selectAll(".limit-scale").attr("transform", "scale(" + (MAX_SCALE/currentScale) + ")");
```

The same logic can be applied to `stroke` and `font-size` styles.

Comment: That's just how it works. But I just didn't know how to write the code. Finally I managed to port: http://bl.ocks.org/eyaler/10586116  to d3.v4.js